# asp.net mvc Linq exclude values from other table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have an exhibition scenario.

How do I exclude a list of available Stands below, from the drop down list I would show in the Exhibitor view.

In Sql I would:

```
Select StandID, Description from Stand 
Where StandID not in (Select StandID from Exhibitor)
```

Exhibitors register - and select the stand they want from a dropdown list (StandID/Stand) as per the model below:

```
 public class Exhibitor
{
    public int ExhibitorID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public int StandID { get; set; }
    public virtual Stand Stand { get; set; }
 }
```

The Stand Model is as follows:

```
  public class Stand
{
    public int StandID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Booked { get; set; }
}
```

I can get a list of Stands as follows:

```
var stands = db.Stands.ToList().Where(s => s.Booked==false)
          .Select(s => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = s.StandID.ToString(),
              Text = s.StandNumber + ": " + s.Description + ": " + s.Size + ": £" + s.Rate.ToString()
          });
```

But how do I exclude the (Select StandID from Exhibitor) from the stands list?

I tried:

```
var booked = db.Exhibitors.Select(s => new { s.StandID }).ToList();
```

then using:

```
var stands = db.Stands.ToList().Where(s => s.Booked==false)
          .Except(booked)
          .Select(s => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = s.StandID.ToString(),
              Text = s.StandNumber + ": " + s.Description + ": " + s.Size + ": £" + s.Rate.ToString()
          });
```

But that didn't work.

> **UPDATE**

This appears to work - but I'm no expert, so would appreciate any advise on if it;s the best practice way or not?

```
var stands = db.Stands.ToList().Where(s => !db.Exhibitors
.Any(bk => bk.StandID == s.StandID) && s.Booked == false)
          .Select(s => new SelectListItem
          {
              Value = s.StandID.ToString(),
              Text = s.StandNumber + ": " + s.Description + ": " + s.Size + ": £" + s.Rate.ToString()
          });
```

Thanks for any help?

Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Linq Contains() method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.contains.aspx

```
var booked = db.Exhibitors.Select(s => s.StandID).ToList();
var stand = db.Stands.Where(s=>s.Booked == false 
                                       && !booked.Contains(s.StandId)
              .Select(s => new SelectListItem
              {
                  Value = s.StandID.ToString(),
                  Text = s.StandNumber + ": " + s.Description + ": " + s.Size + ": £" + s.Rate.ToString()
              });
```

I see you updated your question about best practices, too. There's a lot of optimization that can be done to your technique. First, read about the differences between `IEnumerable` and `IQueryable`.

Specifically speaking, you should remove the `ToList()` from `Stands.ToList().Where()`. By performing `ToList()` before `Where()` you're bringing back all of your rows from the db, and then processing them in memory. This **could** be very costly. If you perform `Stands.Where(...)` then your filtering will be done in sql and only the rows you want will be returned.

Generally, save your ToList() to be your final step, and actively decide if you need the list to be constructed at all.

Comment: Hi - I received the error: Error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>.Contains(AnonymousType#1)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Updated my answer. You don't need to create an anonymous object for your "booked" list. You need a List<int>. (I just removed your new statement)

Comment: This helped me figure out my own solution.  Thank you @BZink

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way is always to create a model that you want as output, map the output to that model and return it. This will also help the client side to get a definitive model to stick to and implement.

Also complex select queries in LINQ are generated on the fly which takes more time than a well structured stored procedure, which is pre-compiled. Consider this if you are expecting faster responses.